# How do I move a SCNNode in my scene through touch? SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a plane 3d model I made and imported from blender. Built my scene using `let scene =  SCNScene(named:  "MainGame.scnassets/plane.scn")` to start the scene. I want to be able to tap and move my plane around the scene. I'm new to 3d swift.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I got it

```swift
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            touchLocation = CGPointToSCNVector3(view: sceneView, depth: 0, point:touch.location(in: sceneView) )
            plane?.position.x = Float(touchLocation.x)
            plane?.position.y = Float(touchLocation.y)
        }
    }
```

```swift
func CGPointToSCNVector3(view: SCNView, depth: Float, point: CGPoint) -> SCNVector3 {
        let projectedOrigin = view.projectPoint(SCNVector3Make(0, 0, depth))
        let locationWithz   = SCNVector3Make(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), projectedOrigin.z)
        return view.unprojectPoint(locationWithz)
    }
```